# How do opencv boxFilter or blur work on image borading?

Tags: opencv

I tried to implement my personal blur filter, but I got confused with the detailed implementation of `cv2.blur` on boarding of images. In my code, I regard those pixels out of image as 0, which performs as padding operation in CNN does. However, it seems that OpenCV does different operations. Here is my implementation:

```
def _blur2D(I, r):
    """
    Helper method of blur2D
    """
    (rows, cols) = I.shape
    ret = np.zeros_like(I, dtype=np.float32)

    I_cum = np.cumsum(I, axis=0)
    ret[0:r+1, :] = I_cum[r:2*r+1, :]
    ret[r+1:rows-r, :] = I_cum[2*r+1:rows, :] - I_cum[0:rows-2*r-1, :]
    ret[rows-r:rows, :] = np.tile(I_cum[rows-1, :], (r, 1)) - \
                          I_cum[rows-2*r-1:rows-r-1, :]

    I_cum = np.cumsum(ret, axis=1)
    ret[:, 0:r+1] = I_cum[:, r:2*r+1]
    ret[:, r+1:cols-r] = I_cum[:, 2*r+1:cols] - I_cum[:, 0:cols-2*r-1]
    ret[:, cols-r:cols] = np.tile(I_cum[:, cols-1], (r, 1)).T - \
                          I_cum[:, cols-2*r-1:cols-r-1]

    return ret


def blur2D(I, r):
    """
    This method should perform like cv2.blur().

    Parameters
    ----------
    I: NDArray of 2D
    r: float, radius of blur filter

    Returns
    -------
    Blurred output of I.
    """
    eye = np.ones_like(I, dtype=np.float32)
    N = _blur2D(eye, r)
    ret = _blur2D(I, r)
    return ret / N
```

Given input of a matrix `I`:

```
[[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.]
 [  8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.]
 [ 15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.]
 [ 22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.  28.]
 [ 29.  30.  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.]
 [ 36.  37.  38.  39.  40.  41.  42.]
 [ 43.  44.  45.  46.  47.  48.  49.]]
```

`blur2D(I, r=1)` gives output (when `radius=1`, `kernel size = (3, 3)`):

```
[[  5.    5.5   6.5   7.5   8.5   9.5  10. ]
 [  8.5   9.   10.   11.   12.   13.   13.5]
 [ 15.5  16.   17.   18.   19.   20.   20.5]
 [ 22.5  23.   24.   25.   26.   27.   27.5]
 [ 29.5  30.   31.   32.   33.   34.   34.5]
 [ 36.5  37.   38.   39.   40.   41.   41.5]
 [ 40.   40.5  41.5  42.5  43.5  44.5  45. ]]
```

`cv2.blur(I, (3,3))` gives output:

```
[[  6.33333349   6.66666651   7.66666651   8.66666698   9.66666698   10.66666698  11.        ]
 [  8.66666698   9.          10.          11.          12.          13.   13.33333302]
 [ 15.66666698  16.          17.          18.          19.          20.   20.33333397]
 [ 22.66666603  23.          24.          25.          26.          27.   27.33333397]
 [ 29.66666603  30.          31.          32.          33.          34.   34.33333206]
 [ 36.66666794  37.          38.          39.          40.          41.   41.33333206]
 [ 39.          39.33333206  40.33333206  41.33333206  42.33333206   43.33333206  43.66666794]]
```

How does `cv2.blur` works? Thanks very much if you could take a time to explain it.
PS: I have tried to read source code of opencv, but it is too complicated to understand because of my poor C++ knowledge..

Comment: Here the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga8c45db9afe636703801b0b2e440fce37) for `blur()`. You should look also at the [border type](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5). Probably if you use a border constant with `value=0`, you should get the same result. Looks like you will have to make the border first before, see [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/295/filter2d-and-sepfilter2d-specifying-the-value-for-a-constant-border/).

Comment: Thank you @Catree very much. It makes clear to me.:)